ReactJS PDF Generation from HTML
I have a unique problem where i have to recreate a PDF document into HTML, once the document has been created i add stored data from the database to the HTML Generated Document and display it to the user, the user can then make changes to the document and export it to PDF.
So i have tried about 5 different libraries trying to convert the HTML to PDF, making it look like the original document.
However we have not been successful so far, and need assistance to be able to generate the HTML exactly the same as the original PDF Document.
